# How can I get XML events to Apache Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-integration, integration

There is a clustered (2 node) CRM application in my organisation that uses the spring integration framework (v2.2.0) to publish events whenever an action is performed e.g. create a request, create a customer etc. 
Currently these events just go to a NULL channel but I would like to start forwarding them to an instance of Apache Kafka running on the same network. From there I want to do further processing and analysis on the data to create real time reports using other components.

I've taken a look at the spring-integration-kafka project but it doesn't seem to be compatible with the version of spring
integration used by the application (which I can't upgrade).

I THINK my options for getting these events to Kafka are:

1) Send events to the local file system and have Kafka pull data from there.

2) Send events to an intermediary JMS queue and have Kafka pull data from there.

3) Send events directly to Kafka via HTTP request (?)
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you can't upgrade, just make a copy of the `KafkaProducerMessageHandler` class and adjust it to your current Spring Integration version. In the end it is just a `MessageHandler` to be used from the generic `<int:outbound-channel-adapter>`.

Finally you always can use Kafka `Producer` API directly from the Service Activator method.

Unfortunately all your suggestions are not sufficient because they includes extra network communication layer, meanwhile all we need is just send to Kafka directly.